# metric manupulation in R

Tags: python, r

here is my R code

take a look and give me a  sol

```
data1<-as.matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19))
temp<- c(data1)

print(temp)

print(paste0(temp[0:-3]))

## "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "0"  "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19"
```

how can i get this out put

`"1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "0"  "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16"`

and also i want to one element before `1`  and after `16`

here if  i use `tail` and `head`

```
 temp<- c(data1)


 ret<-c(cumsum(data1))

 a<-tail(ret,n = -3)
 b<- head(ret,n=-3)
 a-b
 #9  13  18  24  31  39  38  48  59  81  84  98 113 129 146 164  
 THIS IS WHAT I GET (wrong) 

 THIS IS WHAT I AM EXPECTING (python can give this) 

 # 9 12 15 18 21 24 17 20 23 36 39 42 45 48 51 54
```

give me suggetion

Comment: It is not clear to me. What is your input? What is your expected output ?

Comment: @RonakShah input  is `data1`  , see after here if i use tail and head.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
head(temp,-3)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

So, ret is the cumulative sum of the data1, it has the values

`[1]   1   3   6  10  15  21  28  36  45  45  56  68  81  95 110 126 143 161 180`

and variable a is `ret` without first 3 elements

`[1]  10  15  21  28  36  45  45  56  68  81  95 110 126 143 161 180`

b is `temp` without last 3 elements

`[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0 11 12 13 14 15 16`

`a-b` means that each b element is substracted from the element with the same position in a

So , `a-b` will equal

`[1]   9  13  18  24  31  39  38  48  59  81  84  98 113 129 146 164`

Comment: i now this way , but now how to add ,element ?

Comment: Function append `Add elements to a vector.`

Let's say you want to add 20 to the temp list, use 

`append (temp, 20)`

If you want to add 0 at the beginning, use 

`append(0, temp)`

Comment: and also sub operation is not working properly , i am puting it here

Comment: You should write your question with a working example. Variable ret is not defined

Comment: sorry , take a look

Comment: Updated the original response

Comment: that is wrong for me , expected i have mentioned there

Comment: The script is working as expected. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: ###9 12 15 18 21 24 17 20 23 36 39 42 45 48 51 54   this is what i what i want after sub operation

Comment: I'm asking about the logic here. I gave you the output of cumsum and maybe you don't want cumsum?

Comment: just tell me , how to add , before and after

Comment: Add an element at the first position or last position? I answered before to use `append` function. 

Otherwise what do you mean by adding before or after?